# How to suppress this JavaScript error: Exception : TypeError: $("j2t-temp-div").down(".j2t_ajax_message") is undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, exception, magento

To reproduce this error, please kindly go to [here](http://www.princessly.com/a-line-strapless-dropped-waist-sleeveless-floor-length-chapel-wedding-dress.html).

Select "Color" and "Size" and click "Add to Cart", when the "loading..." dialog box appears AND before it turns into the "added to cart" dialog box, click anywhere in the shade to cancel the dialog box, and then click any link on the page as fast as you can.

If you are fast enough, you can reproduce this alerted error:

```
Exception : TypeError: $("j2t-temp-div").down(".j2t_ajax_message") is undefined
```

(Firefox 9)

```
Exception : TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

(Chrome 17)

No alerted error for IE 8.

My question is how do I suppress this error. I have accidentally stepped on it several times and I'm sure my users would do that as well by chance. And it doesn't look pretty on a production site.

Is there any way to disable this exception while keeping the AJAX adding to cart feature?

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress it, you can use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof variableHere != 'undefined'){
  // your further code
}
```

For example if you do:

```
alert(someVar);
```

where `someVar` isn't defined before, you will receive:

```
someVar is not defined
```

But when you do:

```
if (typeof someVar == 'undefined'){ ... }
```

It will suppress the error.

---

So you have to figure out which variable is causing that error after which you need to use `typeof` check to suppress the message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for me `$("j2t-temp-div")` is missing `#` or `.`. It depends if `j2t-temp-div` is the `id` of div or `class`. (I don't use jquery for a while, so something could be changed...)

Comment: not related to jquery i guess, prototype selectors look the same and Magento uses prototype. But the idea is the same that either parent element (first selector) or second element (second selector) is missing in markup or is not jet loaded

Comment: It could be related to `jquery`, I suppose `jquery` could use one of them by default... (`#` or `.`)

Comment: but if you open up the referenced link in question you see that $ is used for prototype there jQuery or $j for jquery and J2t_Ajaxcheckout extension that gives out the error message uses prototype